# How to create a multiboot flash drive in Linux?

Tags: linux, dual-boot, iso

I like the way the [yumi](http://www.pendriveapps.com/yumi-multiboot-live-usb-creator/) makes a multiboot flash drive in Windows. In Linux, can I complete the same task as easily as `yumi` does in Windows?

With `yumi`, I just browse to selected iso (i.e. DVDwindows.iso) and I can prepare the multiboot flash drive ready in few moments.

Comment: I created multi-boot USB drive **manually** by using [syslinux](http://www.syslinux.org/wiki/index.php/The_SYSLINUX_Project). The hard job need to do is create a working syslinux.cfg (different linux distro use different parameter to specify LiveOS direcotry, need to figure it out first), but once it's done, you only need to extract .iso to different directories in USB drive (if works for updated version of some distro too). currently i have SystemRescueCD/PartedMagic/CloneZilla/GParted/CentOS6/Fedora17-Updated/Fedora18/Debian6/Ubuntu12 live-OS in a 8GB USB drive.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of different ways to this. You can choose to setup multiboot using :

1. Grub2 . Follow instructions from [here.](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/boot-multiple-iso-from-usb-via-grub2-using-linux)
2. Multisystem. Follow instructions from [here.](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/multiboot-create-a-multiboot-usb-from-linux/)

The instructions for grub2 are simple enough to follow.As given there , adding an unlisted OS would require you to edit the menu entry for that OS in '/boot/grub/grub.cfg'.

Comment: I have a more detailed tutorial regarding creation of a [GRUB2 multiboot/multiISO LiveUSB](https://bitbucket.org/tlroche/install_resizable_encrypted_lmde/src/HEAD/create_LMDE_liveUSB.rst) than the one listed above (in this answer). Feel free to fork and make pull request(s)!